# How can I make a duplicate set of radio buttons that also duplicate their selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried variations of the following:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
var name = $(this).attr('name');
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('#' + id).attr('checked');    
});
```

What I want to have is a set of options duplicated, one set will be in a hidden div with "further options" so if the further information button is hit, the current div hides and the hidden one shows but keeps all the existing selected options from the first view the user had.

Something like:

Opt1
Opt2
Opt3

Opt1
Opt2 Opt3 Opt4 Opt5

So when the first set hides and the second set shows, the first 3 options match whatever options were selected before the div change over.

Comment: you could use `.clone()`

Comment: Thanks I will look in to that, never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

I think my suggestion might work for you.

You don't need to duplicate the set of radio buttons.
you just need to divide the options in two div's. further option div is initially hidden.
for eg.

```
<div class="optionGrp1">
  //op1, op2, op3
  <div class="further_option" style="display:none">
  // op4, op5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct to be fair, based on the information I have given you that would be an option.  I was trying to avoid doing it this way because as part of a bigger picture it would be a recode of part of the site.  I think I'm just going to have to do it that way though.  Thanks for your input.